# How to activate the Python Virtual Environment

Tags: python, opencv, virtualization

I'm trying to install OpenCV in my raspberry (I'm new with it) and I followed this [post](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-4-4-on-raspberry-pi/). I have done all the steps from 0 to 6.

All this installation it's done in a virtual environment, but now I don't know how to activate this environment. The post says that I have to introduce this line `workon OpenCV-3.4.4-py3` but as @Heath Raftery and @Shreyas Murali say the correct line is `workoncv-3.4.4 OpenCV-3.4.4-py3` because in the step 3 we do

```
echo "alias workoncv-$cvVersion=\"source $cwd/OpenCV-$cvVersion-py3/bin/activate\"" >> ~/.bashrc
```

I tried to execute `workoncv-3.4.4 OpenCV-3.4.4-py3` in the folder "OpenCV-3.4.4-py3" but it fails and appear the following error message

> bash: workon: command not found

I'm pretty sure it's a stupid question but I'm really lost with it.

How can I activate the virtual environment?

¡Salud!

Comment: a better tag for the question would be `python`.

Answer (score 1):

relevant sections from that post go like so:

step 0: defines the opencv version

```bsh
echo "OpenCV installation by learnOpenCV.com"
cvVersion="3.4.4"
```

step 3: sets up an alias

```bsh
# Install virtual environment
python3 -m venv OpenCV-"$cvVersion"-py3
echo "# Virtual Environment Wrapper" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "alias workoncv-$cvVersion=\"source $cwd/OpenCV-$cvVersion-py3/bin/activate\"" >> ~/.bashrc
source "$cwd"/OpenCV-"$cvVersion"-py3/bin/activate
#############
```

The alias would expand to `workoncv-3.4.4` and not just the suffix `workon`

Given the alias uses `$cwd`, you need to navigate to the parent folder that contains the virtual env folder `OpenCV-3.4.4-py3` before executing the alias

Comment: As I said to Heath Raftery, I am trying to execute the comand `workoncv-3.4.4` in the directory `OpenCV-3.4.4-py3` and says the same error. Maybe I forget to do that echo, I think I would do all the installation again and ensure I do this step. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you executed this line in step 3:

```
echo "alias workoncv-$cvVersion=\"source $cwd/OpenCV-$cvVersion-py3/bin/activate\"" >> ~/.bashrc
```

It should have added a line to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file. The line should look something like:

```
alias workoncv-3.4.4="source /your/working/path/OpenCV-3.4.4-py3/bin/activate"
```

First make sure that line exists by executing `less ~/.bashrc` and scrolling to the end of the file (hit `q` to exit), then log out and log back in to ensure the line takes effect.

Now you can just type `workoncv-3.4.4` at the command line at any time to activate the venv.

Comment: I am trying to execute the comand `workoncv-3.4.4` in the directory `OpenCV-3.4.4-py3` and says the same error. Maybe I forget to do that echo, I think I would do all the installation again and ensure I do this step. Thank you

Comment: It doesn't matter which directory you do it in. Are you sure you're executing `workoncv-3.4.4` without any spaces? In your original post you say you're executing `workon`, which results in the error `workon: command not found`, as expected, because `workon` doesn't exist, only `workoncv-3.4.4`. Try executing `alias`. It should list `workoncv-3.4.4` as one of your aliases. Does it? And is that what you're executing? If so, you need to look deeper at what's in the corresponding `activate` script. Maybe the issue is there, but that's not the question you've asked.

Comment: I am executing `workoncv-3.4.4` and says the same error, and in `alias`don`t appears anything about workon

Comment: What's the output of `alias | grep workon` ?

Comment: `alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'` Nothing about `alias | grep workon`

Comment: I'm not sure if you're having me on, but just in case, please copy the following text and paste it into your terminal: `alias | grep workon`. Press enter, then copy and paste what appears into your comment.

Comment: Nothing appears, (sorry for my english and thanks for the patience)

Comment: Okay, fantastic, the alias hasn't worked. Now go back to my answer and read it carefully. Comment on what happens when you follow the instructions. We can then delete all these comments.

Comment: I executed `~/.bashrc` and in the last line appears `alias workoncv-="source /OpenCV--py3/bin/activate"`, understand that now I have to write `workoncv-3.4.4` but says error too...

Comment: I hope you mean `less ~/.bashrc`. Okay, great, that means you didn't successfully follow Step 0 in the instructions in the original post you linked (`cvVersion` is not defined). Start again, and follow the instructions very carefully. Post a question or do some Googling as soon as you something doesn't seem to work right.

Comment: I did it all again and now when I execute `less ~/.bashrc` appears what you said, `alias workoncv-3.4.4="source /home/pi/OpenCV-3.4.4-py3/bin/activate`, but when I execute `workoncv-3.4.4 OpenCV-3.4.4-py3` fails yet... (Thanks for all)

Comment: Much better! Please update your question and we'll delete all this and have another go. Remember to specify **exactly** what you typed and **exactly** what the output is.